# Component inside form Angular 2

Tags: angular

So here is my parent form:

```
<form [ngFormModel]="formModel">
    <ui-form-control *ngFor="#key of controlsKeys"
                     [control]="formModel.controls[key]"
                     [name]="key">
    </ui-form-control>
</form>
```

here is my component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'ui-form-control'
})
@View({
    template: `
    <label>{{name}}: </label>
    <input [ngFormControl]="control" [placeholder]="name">
    `,
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class UiFormControl{
    @Input() control: UiControl;
    @Input() name: string;

    constructor(){
    }
}
```

I can see the Control value inside my ui-form-component, but when I've change it formModel-ComponentGroup doesn't update. So it looks like two way binding don't work here.

Actually if i'll remove my `<ui-form-control>` and place simple `<input>` tag instead it will work and formModel will update as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should use two way binding here in your sub component with both `@Input` and `@Output`. The latter is notified the parent component that the control changes within the sub component. I think about something like that:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ui-form-control'
  template: `
    <label>{{name}}: </label>
    <input [ngFormControl]="control" (change)="inputChanged()" [placeholder]="name">
  `,
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class UiFormControl{
  @Input() control: UiControl;
  @Output() controlChange: EventEmitter;
  @Input() name: string;

  constructor(){
    this.controlChange = new EventEmitter();
  }

  inputChanged() {
    this.controlChange.emit(this.control);
  }
}
```

I used an intermediate approach for the field of my forms by leveraging `ng-content`.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'field',
  template: `
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm" [ngClass]="{'has-error':control && !control.valid}">
      <label for="for"
         class="col-sm-3 control-label">{{label}}</label>

      <div #content class="col-sm-8">
        <ng-content ></ng-content>
        <span *ngIf="control && !control.valid" class="help-block text-danger">
          <span *ngIf="control?.errors?.required">The field is required</span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class FormFieldComponent {
  @Input()
  label: string;

  @Input()
  state: Control;
}
```

And its use within the parent component:

```
<form [ngFormModel]="companyForm">
  <field label="Name" [state]="companyForm.controls.name">
    <input [ngFormControl]="companyForm.controls.name" 
           [(ngModel)]="company.name"/> {{name.valid}}
  </field>
</form>
```

That way the inputs, selects, textareas remain managed within the parent component but field components tackles field formatting (structure for Bootstrap3 for example) and leverage controls to display errors if any. This way you don't need two way binding anymore for field component and the latter is more generic ;-)

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Looks so weird. Cause if I'll have such a big form it will be not that good to manage all of this events. I want to decouple inputs from form management as much as possible.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Having a dedicated component for each form elements could be a bit too much ;-) That's why I introduced an intermediate approach. I would create a dedicated component for something that be handled by an input only. For example, a list of labels. Does that make sense?

Comment: I want to create form declaratively. Not dedicated control for each element all around application. I want to pass some metadata to form-builder and it will compose the form to me. Like formly or similar. That's why I want to have such structure: ui-form -> ui-form-component. ui form will compose ui-form-components for me based on some metadata. And that's it.

Comment: the only question why passing Control object to ui-form-component and updating it inside doesn't work. Because it is the same object that I have in ui-form. So i thought that input should update Control's value how it say... by reference.

Comment: In fact, it's actually updated by reference. I just made a try ;-)

Comment: Here is a plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/ucVBG27RtDeSWa5t5SRi?p=preview. When you put something in the input, you'll see that the field control and the form one are updated... Is it the behavior you expect?

Comment: Exactly! Trying to achieve this in my code but for now without any results

Comment: What is the difference? I would be interested in knowing how to initialize the controls within your form control ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since you asked it but for someone who have the same problem, maybe the awnser of AJT82 to my question could help you:
[Problem with mat-select when submitting form in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58023895/problem-with-mat-select-when-submitting-form-in-angular)

Comment: Please provide a solution with an example if possible and not just links on other SO posts.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem but it seems to be similar to the problem I had, wich was awnsered on my post, I just put the link there if it can help

Answer (score -1):

What two way binding were you expecting?

You can get a two way binding-ish by setting a property both as a (one way) binding and an event. Actually there is a little more going on but the shortcut is simple like this:

```
<input [(ng-model)]="myField" >
```

You can read more at [Victor Savkins blog](http://victorsavkin.com/post/119943127151/angular-2-template-syntax).