# Problem with mat-select when submitting form in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use Angular7 with Angular Material, I have a form which contain a component which contain a mat-select.
The select in the form out of my component work but not the one into my component.

Viewable on this stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hqkcgq

The actual result is that submiting form don't send the value of the select, but it have to. 
You can see in console when submiting the form.

edit: the stackblitz is edited and now work as I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future, please add all relevant code to the question itself. A StackBlitz is great, but it should just be an addition to the question :)

But to your code, in your child component you need to provide `ControlContainer`. So add to your code:

```
import { ControlContainer, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-comp',
  templateUrl: './my-comp.component.html',
  viewProviders: [ { provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm } ]
})
```

Please refer to the article by the awesome Alexey Zuev: **[Nested Template driven Forms](https://medium.com/@a.yurich.zuev/angular-nested-template-driven-form-4a3de2042475)**

As a sidenote, in all places you are providing `[ngModel]="''"`, you can just use `ngModel` to register the form control.

**[Your forked StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sp8yh7?file=src/app/my-comp/my-comp.component.ts)**

Comment: Thanks a lots, for the [ngModel], its because I take it from mycode where I have to use [], thanks too for the link, I didn't found it during my research